# How to get current value of field in Activity when using DexClassLoader?

Tags: java, android, dexclassloader

I have a field in MainActivity like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static String field = "abc";

private void setField(Intent intent) {
    String field2;
    if (intent != null && (field2 = intent.getStringExtra("field")) != null) {
        field = field2;

    }
}

/* access modifiers changed from: protected */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView((int) R.layout.activity_main);
    setField(getIntent());
....
```

and I load method from Dex file with this code

```
Class<?> classToLoad = new DexClassLoader(codeFile.getAbsolutePath(), tmpDir.getAbsolutePath(), (String) null, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()).loadClass("com.example.MyClass");
        Method method = classToLoad.getDeclaredMethod("run", new Class[0]);
        method.invoke(classToLoad, new Object[0]);
```

So, In **run()** method, how I can get current value of *field*? Thank you!

```
public static void run()  {
    // How?

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution using ***getContextClassLoader***

```
Class clazz = callerClasses.loadClass("com.example.MainActivity");       
Fields field = new Fields();
Field field= clazz.getDeclaredField("field");
flag.setAccessible(true);
Log.d(TAG, "field: " + flag.get(field));
```

Which "Fields" is an inner class in Dex code

```
private static class Fields {

    private static String field = "test";
}
```